# cross domain loading and executing JS

Tags: javascript

I am loading the JS file using javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {

         var fileref=document.createElement('script')
         fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
        fileref.setAttribute("src", "js/index.js")

        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)

        }
```

the index.js file has the following line

```
document.write('<a href="#" target="_blank">link</a>');
```

I am sure the file loads ( tested with an alert()) but for some reason the anchor is nowhere to be found on my page. There does not seem to be any js errors either.

the same line if included in the page directly works fine

FYI : this JS is for a plugin which will be cross domain installed. I am aware that the could be limitations there but would appreciate any guidance.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.write` is really only useful for scripts that are executed inline with the parsing of the page. If you call `document.write` later, it implicitly does a `document.open`, which wipes out the page's content. I'm not sure why you're not seeing that, given what you've described.

When adding content after the initial page load, one uses the DOM, e.g.:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.innerHTML = "link";
a.href = "#";
a.target = "_blank";

document.body.appendChild(a); // Or, of course, append to something more targeted
```

In terms of loading scripts cross-domain, there's no problem with that at all. What you're doing is fine, although you can shorten it a bit and it's best **not** to rely on the horror that is JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion:

```
var fileref = document.createElement('script');
fileref.src = "js/index.js";
document.documentElement.appendChild(fileref);
```

There's no need for `type` (JavaScript is the default), and `src` is a reflected property (as is `type`, if you do want to go ahead and use it). There's no need to append scripts to the `head` element, anywhere in the document element (`html`) is fine.

Comment: Works Great! just a quick follow up. How would add style attribute to the anchor? a.style doesn't seem to work. thanks again!

Comment: got it! : .setAttribute("style","color:red") ... etc

Comment: @salmane: You can use the `style` property: `a.style.color = "red";` For things like `background-color`, you use the camelCase name: `a.style.backgroundColor = "#aaa";`.

Comment: thanks! i have a longer list of style attributes perhaps it is more efficient to just go with setAttribute. Unless you think otherwise?

Comment: @salmane: I've never used `setAttribute` to set style information, so I don't now how cross-browser compatible and such it is. On the face of it, you'd expect it to be fine. BTW, this stuff is one of many reasons I recommend using a good library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). Check out jQuery's [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css) function, for instance.

Comment: Thanks again TJ. I would much rather use Jquery. Its my library of choice which is why I am rusty on plain javascript:).since this is for a plugin i wanted to keep it minimalistic and reduce any possible conflict for users.(plugins relying on older Jquery versions for example)

Comment: Just a follow up. Css should be set like this : a.style.cssText = "color:red; ..." otherwise IE7 breaks ( ... of course)

Answer (score 1):

document.write isn't what you want to use here as it's more suited to inline JS (JS in your HTML document). Could you not write the hyperlink to the DOM using `.innerHTML` (making sure that the element you wish to modify the innerHTML is loaded)?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML